# Flutter Image not being displayed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

So I'm trying to make a page with an image background and this is my code:

```
body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("loginBackground"),
          ),
        )
      ),
```

However when I run this it opens a new editor with some of Flutters code, and a line is highlighted yellow, which I think means a breakpoint (correct me if I'm wrong). The file name is 'image_provider.dart' and this is the relevant code (I have indicated the highlighted line):

```
@protected
  Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync(AssetBundleImageKey key, DecoderCallback decode) async {
    ByteData? data;
    // Hot reload/restart could change whether an asset bundle or key in a
    // bundle are available, or if it is a network backed bundle.
    try {
      data = await key.bundle.load(key.name);
    } on FlutterError {
      PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.evict(key);


      rethrow;          // THIS IS THE HIGHLIGHTED LINE

    }
    // `key.bundle.load` has a non-nullable return type, but might be null when
    // running with weak checking, so we need to null check it anyway (and
    // ignore the warning that the null-handling logic is dead code).
    if (data == null) { // ignore: dead_code
      PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.evict(key);
      throw StateError('Unable to read data');
    }
    return await decode(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  }
}
```

I don't know what this means, so any help would be really appreciated.
This is the image (Scroll):
[image]

(sorry for it being so big)
If you need more details just comment :)

Comment: Make sure you have correctly specified the filepath to your asset, and to include the file extension. Also do not forget to specify the assets folder in your pubspec.yaml. see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Comment: Add the extension for image i.e jpg/png etc , Also try posting the error that you see after you run with run without debugging  mode in vscode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the `assetImage` the synatx is usually like this :

`image: AssetImage("images/loginBackground.png")`

also if you didn't enable your assets in pubspec.yaml by doing this in your assets section :

```
 assets:
    - images/
```

also a little bit of error code will help

Answer (score 1):

try AssetImage('assets/loginBackground.png'), assuming you've created a folder assets in your project with all your images.
You also need to specify

assets:

- assets/

in your pubspec.yaml file